# How can I access the unique element once inside the change function?

Tags: jquery, html, razor

Using Razor with models. Read Comment in Script.

**HTML**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.List[i].information, Model.ListDropdown(), new { @id = "GetList" + i})
```

**Script**

```
$("[id^=GetList]").change(function () {
    // How can I get the 'i' value after the id? 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `replace` the `GetList` in the `id` attribute of the element. An easier way however, is to use a `data` attribute. Also, I added a `class` attribute to save you having to use the (rather slow) 'attribute starts with' selector.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.List[i].information, 
    Model.ListDropdown(), 
    new { @class = "list-item", data_id = i }
)
```

You can then retrieve this value directly in your `change` handler:

```
$(".list-item").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
}
```

Note that `this` within the `change` function block refers to the `select` which raised the event.